Tank Duel Game in Greenfoot Error bulletCollision
I am making a simple two-player game in Greenfoot about tanks. They shoot at each other.
My problem is that when I add an additional method in the Bullet1 or Bullet2 class, the game errors when one player hits the other (e.g., player 1 hits player 2 with a bullet). It gives me a terminal error:
Caused by: greenfoot.ActorRemovedFromWorld
at greenfoot.World.removeObject(World.java:466)
at Bullet1.checkCollision(Bullet1.java:34)
at Bullet1.act(Bullet1.java:23)
... 4 more ....

This is my main world:
import greenfoot.*;  // (World, Actor, GreenfootImage, Greenfoot and MouseInfo)

public class BATTLEFIELD extends World {

    public BATTLEFIELD() {
        super(800, 400, 1, false);
        prepare();
    }
    
    private void prepare() {
        Wall wall = new Wall();
        addObject(wall, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2 - 110);
        Wall2 wall2 = new Wall2();
        addObject(wall2, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2 + 110);
        
        Counter counter1 = new Counter("Player 1 HP: ");
        Counter counter2 = new Counter("Player 2 HP: ");
        
        addObject(counter1, getWidth()/2 - 320, getHeight()/2 - 180);
        addObject(counter2, getWidth()/2 + 320, getHeight()/2 - 180);
        
        Player1 player1 = new Player1(counter1);
        Player2 player2 = new Player2(counter2);
        
        addObject(player1, 50, getHeight() / 2);
        addObject(player2, getWidth() - 50, getHeight() / 2);
    }
}

Bullet1:
import greenfoot.*;  // (World, Actor, GreenfootImage, Greenfoot and MouseInfo)

public class Bullet1 extends Actor {
    private Player1 player1;
    private GreenfootImage hitImage;
    private int damage = 5;

    public Bullet1(Player1 player1) {
        this.player1 = player1;
        hitImage = new GreenfootImage("explode1.png");
    }

    public void act() {
        move(20);
        checkCollision();
        bulletCollision(); // this is the problem when I add any additional method in this act method
    }

    private void checkCollision() {
        Actor player = getOneIntersectingObject(Player2.class);
        if (player != null) {
            ((Player2)player).takeDamage(damage);
            setImage(hitImage);
            Greenfoot.playSound("takingDamageSFX.mp3");
            Greenfoot.delay(4);
            getWorld().removeObject(this);
        }
    }

    private void bulletCollision() {
        Actor bullet2 = getOneIntersectingObject(Bullet2.class);
        if (bullet2 != null) {
            setImage(hitImage);
            Greenfoot.delay(4);
            World world = getWorld();
            world.removeObject(bullet2);
            world.removeObject(this);
        }
    }
}

Bullet2:
import greenfoot.*;  // (World, Actor, GreenfootImage, Greenfoot and MouseInfo)

public class Bullet2 extends Actor {
    private Player2 player2;
    private int damage = 5;
    private GreenfootImage hitImage;

    public Bullet2(Player2 player2) {
        this.player2 = player2;
        setRotation(180);
        hitImage = new GreenfootImage("explode1.png");
    }

    public void act() {
        move(20);
        checkCollision();
        bulletCollision(); // this is the problem when I add any additional method in this act method
    }

    private void checkCollision() {
        Actor player = getOneIntersectingObject(Player1.class);
        if (player != null) {
            ((Player1)player).takeDamage(damage);
            setImage(hitImage);
            Greenfoot.playSound("takingDamageSFX.mp3");
            Greenfoot.delay(4);
            getWorld().removeObject(this);
        }
    }

    private void bulletCollision() {
        Actor bullet1 = getOneIntersectingObject(Bullet1.class);
        if (bullet1 != null) {
            setImage(hitImage);
            Greenfoot.delay(4);
            World world = getWorld();
            world.removeObject(bullet1);
            world.removeObject(this);
        }
    }
}

Player1:
import greenfoot.*;

public class Player1 extends Actor {
    private int speed = 5; 
    private int reloadTime = 10; 
    private int reloadDelay = 0;
    private int hp = 100;
    private GreenfootImage explodedImage;
    private GreenfootImage shieldedImage;
    private GreenfootImage baseImage;
    private Counter counter;
    private boolean shieldActive = false;
    private int shieldDuration = 300; 
    private int shieldTimer = 0; 
    
    public Player1(Counter counter) {
        setRotation(270);
        this.counter = counter;
        counter.setValue(hp);
        explodedImage = new GreenfootImage("explode2.png");
        shieldedImage = new GreenfootImage("shielded_blue_tank.png");
        baseImage = new GreenfootImage("tank_blue.png");
    }

    public void act() {
        movementKeys();
        checkBoundaries();
        manageShield();
        reloadDelay++;
    }

    private void movementKeys() {
        if (Greenfoot.isKeyDown("w")) {
            setLocation(getX(), getY() - speed);
        }
        if (Greenfoot.isKeyDown("s")) {
            setLocation(getX(), getY() + speed);
        }
        if (Greenfoot.isKeyDown("space")) {
            shootBullet();
        }
    }

    private void shootBullet() {
        if (reloadDelay >= reloadTime) { 
            getWorld().addObject(new Bullet1(this), getX(), getY());
            Greenfoot.playSound("firingSFX.mp3");
            reloadDelay = 0;
        }
    }

    public void takeDamage(int damage) {
        hp -= damage;
        counter.setValue(hp);
        if (hp <= 0) {
            getWorld().addObject(new Player2Wins(), getWorld().getWidth()/2, getWorld().getHeight()/2);
            setImage(explodedImage);
            Greenfoot.playSound("tankExplodedSFX.mp3");
            Greenfoot.delay(40);
            getWorld().removeObject(this);
            Greenfoot.stop();
        }
    }

    private void checkBoundaries() {
        int y = getY();
        int worldHeight = getWorld().getHeight();
        
        if (y <= 0) {
            setLocation(getX(), 1);
        } else if (y >= worldHeight - 1) {
            setLocation(getX(), worldHeight - 2);
        }
    }

    private void manageShield() {
        if (shieldActive) {
            shieldTimer++;
            if (shieldTimer >= shieldDuration) {
                deactivateShield();
            }
        }
    }

    public void activateShield() {
        shieldActive = true;
        setImage(shieldedImage);
    }

    public void deactivateShield() {
        shieldActive = false;
        setImage(baseImage);
    }

    public boolean isShieldActive() {
        return shieldActive;
    }
}

Player2:
import greenfoot.*;

public class Player2 extends Actor {
    private int speed = 5; 
    private int reloadTime = 10;
    private int reloadDelay = 0;
    private int hp = 100;
    private Counter counter;
    private GreenfootImage explodedImage;
    
    public Player2(Counter counter) {
        GreenfootImage image = getImage();
        image.mirrorVertically();
        setImage(image);
        setRotation(270);
        this.counter = counter;
        counter.setValue(hp);
        explodedImage = new GreenfootImage("explode2.png");
    }

    public void act() {
        movementKeys();
        checkBoundaries();
        reloadDelay++;
    }

    private void movementKeys() {
        if (Greenfoot.isKeyDown("up")) {
            setLocation(getX(), getY() - speed);
        }
        if (Greenfoot.isKeyDown("down")) {
            setLocation(getX(), getY() + speed);
        }
        if (Greenfoot.isKeyDown("enter")) {
            shootBullet();
        }
    }

    private void shootBullet() {
        if (reloadDelay >= reloadTime) { 
            getWorld().addObject(new Bullet2(this), getX(), getY());
            Greenfoot.playSound("firingSFX.mp3");
            reloadDelay = 0;
        }
    }

    public void takeDamage(int damage) {
        hp -= damage;
        counter.setValue(hp);
        if (hp <= 0) {
            setImage(explodedImage);
            Greenfoot.playSound("tankExplodedSFX.mp3");
            Greenfoot.delay(40);
            getWorld().addObject(new Player1Wins(), getWorld().getWidth()/2, getWorld().getHeight()/2);
            getWorld().removeObject(this);
            Greenfoot.stop();
        }
    }

    private void checkBoundaries() {
        int y = getY();
        int worldHeight = getWorld().getHeight();
        
        if (y <= 0) {
            setLocation(getX(), 1);
        } else if (y >= worldHeight - 1) {
            setLocation(getX(), worldHeight - 2);
        }
    }
}

I expect the error to be resolved when I add the bulletCollision method in the act method of the Bullet classes.

It would be helpful to have more of that error message. Is there any way to expand it out?

Also, you have a lot of duplicated code between Bullet/Player 1 and 2. It might be a good project to figure out how you can combine each into one class.

Apparently (read and understand the error message!) the bullet is already removed from the world. -- Now you have at least two options. 1) Read your code carefully to find why the bullet is already removed when you call getWorld().removeObject(this); where the error message points to. 2) Add debugging statements (for example System.out.println("<some helpful text>");) before all getWorld().removeObject(this); statements in the Bullet? classes to find it. -- When you have done this, come back and [edit] your question to add your findings, if they don't help you for correction.

"the busybee" has given you the basic problem.  It is not allowed to interact with the world after you have removed yourself from the world.  The checkCollision method can remove you from the world but you will still execute the bulletCollision method regardless.  One way to solve this is to make checkCollision return a boolean (say, true for when you have removed yourself from the world, and false if not), and then change the relevant two lines in the bullets' act:
if (!checkCollision())
   bulletCollision();

